# How to find all elements and click on them one by one

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation

I'm building a final project and I got stuck in a problem.
Website: trello.com
I have a page that contains buttons with boards that i have created and button to create a board.

I try to store all these buttons, then locate them by text and click on them.

The problem is this, I manage to access all the buttons, but can not click on them
For example: there are three buttons (see picture), the third button is "create new board".
According to the console, I can import his text, but can not click it (after command click nothing happens).
I'm noob, so I hope I've listed everything, and I'll be happy to help.

This is my code:

There is the pic of the trello page with the boards.
https://ibb.co/kmV6V4n

```
private By mainBoardSelectorList = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"content\"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/ul");

public WebElement getMainBoardSelectorList() {
        return driver.findElement(mainBoardSelectorList);
}

   @Test
    public void getAllBoardsAndClick(){

        methodsManager.logIn();
        BoardsPage boardsPage = new BoardsPage(driver);
        System.out.println(boardsPage.getMainBoardSelectorList().getText());
        WebElement el = boardsPage.getMainBoardSelectorList();
        if (el.getText().contains("Create new board")){
            el.click();
        }
    }
```

Jul 11, 2019 12:42:26 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
hj,
Untitled board
Create new board

Answer (score 0):

1. Double check your selector as it might match something which is not clickable, or clickable but resulting into nothing. Use [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) to find out what are the matches as you might get false positive results
2. It is possible to locate element [by partial link text](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ByPartialLinkText.html) like:

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Create new board"));
   ```
3. There is [findElements() function](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-) which returns the [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of WebElements which is more suitable for your use case
4. Be aware that once you click the link and navigate away from the page all the WebElements will be invalidated and you will get [StaleElementReferenceException](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/StaleElementReferenceException.html) so either consider re-do the "find" once you're back or better go for [Page Object Model design pattern](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Design+Patterns+-+Page+Object+Model)  which implements [lazy initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) tactic when it comes to locating the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on `li` tags not `ul`
You can change your function `getMainBoardSelectorList()` to return
`List<WebElement>` instead of `WebElement` .

```
public List<WebElement> getMainBoardSelectorList() {
        return driver.findElement(mainBoardSelectorList).findElements(By.tagName("li")));
}
```

Now your method returns all `li` elements(boards) that you need.
I think "Create new board" is always the last one so you can do

```
List<WebElement> els = boardsPage.getMainBoardSelectorList();

els.get(els.size() - 1).click());
```

**Don't forget to handle exceptions**

Answer (score 0):

```
    Step 1: Navigate and Login 

    driver.get("https://trello.com/login");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='user']")).sendKeys("paste your username here");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("paste your password here");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    Step 2: To Click on First Board
    Here in xpath @title is your Board name so create xpath according this, for me test is First board name

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@title='test']/descendant::div")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.navigate().back();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    Step 3 : To Click on Second Board

    Here in xpath @title is your Board name so create xpath according this, for me test1 is Second board name
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@title='test1']/descendant::div")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.navigate().back();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    Step 3 : To Click on Third Board
    For Click on Create new board manage xpath from class name and click on it.

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='board-tile mod-add']/descendant::span")).click();

    by this you can click all your board one by one. You can create function for manage xpath dynamically for board.
```